# Must I finish every mission to unlock Insane, or just the last one?

Tags: gears-of-war-3

To unlock Insane mode, I read that I need to finish the game. Does this mean every single mission, or can I just finish the last mission in someone else's game (co-op) to unlock Insane?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to test this, and beating Myrrah was not enough: indeed, you must finish **every mission** (on any difficulty) to unlock Insane mode.

Answer (score 0):

yes you do need to beat every level. You know you beat the game and went on to insane mode when you see a skull on the top right of your characters choose screen. There is also an insane mode store and let me tell you, its insane :3